# Printing a list of values from array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print the song name and lengths of songs each time the loop finishes. How do I do this? `Report+= songTitles[numSongs] + songLengths[numSongs]`?

Then, I need to do a linear search to remove songs from the playlist. Will I need to use the same report string to let the user see all songs? I just need help with that. Thank you.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class asdf_Playlist {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int MAX_SONGS = 106;
    int totalDuration = 0;
    int numSongs = 0;
    boolean exitVar = false;
    int i = 0;

    String[] songTitles = new String[MAX_SONGS];
    int[] songLengths = new int[MAX_SONGS];

    while (exitVar == false && numSongs <= songTitles.length) {

      do {

        songTitles[numSongs] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a song name, or type -1 to exit");
        if (songTitles[numSongs].equals("")) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: Please enter a valid song name, or type -1 to exit");
        } else if (songTitles[numSongs].equals("-1")) {
          exitVar = true;
        }
      } while (songTitles[numSongs].equals(""));


      do {
        try {
          songLengths[numSongs] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a song length, e.g. 4."));
          if (songLengths[numSongs] > 0) {
            totalDuration += songLengths[numSongs];
          } else {
            songLengths[numSongs] = -1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: please enter a valid song length, e.g. 4.");
          }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          songLengths[numSongs] = -1;
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: please enter a valid song length, e.g. 4.");
        }

      } while (songLengths[numSongs] <= 0);



      boolean addMore = true;

      while ((numSongs <= MAX_SONGS) && (addMore == true)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Song #" + (i+1) + ": " + songTitles[i] + " length: " + songLengths[i] + "\n");
        i++;
        if (songTitles[i] == null) {
          addMore = false;
        }
      }
      numSongs++;
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you mean print to console or file? Do you want to print all songs for each iteration of the loop? What does the `Report` in your question refer to?

Comment: Sorry- I just wanted to print the song titles and lengths each time the loop restarts, so the user can see every song they have entered. That is all I want to do.

Comment: I also needed to use a linear search to remove the songs, and I think I could use a string with a report header (something like 'Song name: , song length: ') to show all the songs, so the user can type the name of the song to remove it from the list.

I just figured I could use a string that concatenates and picks up the previous information entered, so the user can see every single song that was entered, not just the previous one.

Comment: Part of programming is the trial and error process.  You have thoughts about how to solve your problem, so give it a shot.  No harm should come from trying something in programming with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions to make this easier for you.

Firstly, you should create a class to capture you song information rather than having two separate arrays. This will make life much easier for you in the long term (and is better OO practice). You can then create a `toString` method as part of that class to format song information:

```
class Song {
    private final String title;
    private final int length;

    public String toString() {
        return title + ":" + length;
    }
}
```

Your song arrays then become simpler:

```
private Song[] songs = new Song[MAX_SONGS];
```

Printing the entire list can be done in a number of ways. Before Java 8 it would generally look something like:

```
for (Song song: songs)
    System.out.println(song);
```

Since Java 8 was released this can be simplified to:

```
Arrays.stream(songs).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Removing items from an array is not as easy as removing them from a collection. But it's still not too hard:

```
Song[] copy = new Song[MAX_SONGS];
int copiedSongs = 0;
for (Song song: songs)
    if (/* condition for copying */)
        copy[copiedSongs++] = song;
songs = copy;
numSongs = copiedSongs;
```

Again, using Java 8 this has become much simpler:

```
songs = Arrays.stream(songs).filter(/*condition*/).toArray();
numSongs = songs.length;
```